# Jquery to change div background color when radio button selected?

Tags: jquery, css

I have two separate sets of radio buttons and I want its' divs' color to change when its selected.
The behavior I want is quite straightforward, if the radio button is selected, the corresponding div should change color. (And change back to its original color if deselected).

However, the issue is if a radio button in another set is selected, the first set's div changes back to its original color even though one of its radio buttons is still selected. How do I fix this?

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/awGD4/)

Jquery used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        $('div.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
        $(this).closest('div').addClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

Comment: You forgot to add the jQuery framework.. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/wCNAp/1/

Comment: @Sushanth-- why don't you put this as the answer?, because it is xD

Comment: oops, fixed that, but my issue still exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 2nd issue you need to wrap your's inputs for a block into a separate wrapper and change a bit of your code..

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // Only remove the class in the specific `box` that contains the radio
        $this.closest('.box').find('div.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
        $this.closest('.q').addClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box"> 1st set
    <div class="q">
        <input type="radio" id="1" name="11" />
        <label for 1>a</label>
    </div>
    <div class="q">
        <input type="radio" id="2" name="11" />
        <label for 2>b</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <hr> 2nd set
    <div class="q">
        <input type="radio" id="3" name="22" />
        <label for 3>a</label>
    </div>
    <div class="q">
        <input type="radio" id="4" name="22" />
        <label for 4>b</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/wCNAp/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Not jQuery, but you could look into css rules (the nesting is important: the div.highlight and radio need to be siblings):

[Dabblet example of below](http://result.dabblet.com/gist/6127230/9c57d5e6dea629a0352a60d9bdb9ec3b9e19d44e)

```
div.entry {
    position: relative;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 50%;
}
div.entry div.highlight {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
div.entry input:checked ~ div.highlight {
    background-color: orange;
}

<div class="entry">
    <input type="radio" name="list" />This is one option
    <div class="highlight"></div>
</div>
<div class="entry">
    <input type="radio" name="list" />This is another option
    <div class="highlight"></div>
</div>
<div class="entry">
    <input type="radio" name="list" />This is a third option
    <div class="highlight"></div>
</div>
```